# What should I do to solve the issue?

Tags: boot, 20.04, xubuntu, boot-repair, helpfile

I am getting the following error at the time of booting my laptop, I am unable to understand what is the problem in the system.

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with more specific details. Thank you

Comment: Done know please help me.

Comment: No, It doesn't help me, I tried it.

Comment: None of the above helped me.